(CCS) Why can't MSPM0 SDK install Sysconfig?
I'm currently installing Code Composer Studio, but for some reason, it won't let me install SysConfig. I’ve already tried setting it up manually, but that didn’t work either. Has anyone else encountered this issue?



Ha. Ignore my previous comment. Version 1.22 of sysconfig has just appeared on the TI website here - literally 2 minutes ago. Try installing that.

Yeap, it seems to work fine with older versions. Thanks so much for your "little" huge help!

The installer says that it requires sysconfig v1.22.0, however you only have v1.21.0 installed, so it has an unmet dependency.
The MSPM0 v2.03.00.07 version was only released a few days ago, so weird teething issues are not surprising. You could always try the previous version of the software see if that installs.

Literally as I was writing this answer, TI have released the missing sysconfig v1.22.0 version from their releases page. So try downloading and installing that and see if it makes the latest release of MSPM0 work properly.

